# What is the most efficient way to get count of distinct values in a pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, unique, distinct-values

I have a dataframe as shown below.

```
    0   1   2
0   A   B   C
1   B   C   B
2   B   D   E
3   C   E   E
4   B   F   A
```

I need to get **count of unique values from the entire dataframe**, not column-wise unique values.
In the above dataframe, unique values are A, B, C, D, E, F.
So, the result I need is **6**.

I'm achieving this using pandas squeeze, ravel and nunique functions, which converts entire dataframe into a series.

```
pd.Series(df.squeeze().values.ravel()).nunique(dropna=True)
```

Please let me know if there is any better way to achieve this.

Comment: ``len(np.unique(df))``

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`numpy.unique`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.unique.html) with `length` of unique values:

```
out = len(np.unique(df))
6
```

Answer (score 4):

Use `NumPy` for this, as:

```
import numpy as np
print(np.unique(df.values).shape[0])
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `set`, `len` and `flatten` too:

```
len(set(df.values.flatten()))
```

Out:

```
6
```

---

**Timings:** With a dummy dataframe with 6 unique values

```
#dummy data
df = pd.DataFrame({'Day':np.random.choice(['aa','bbbb','c','ddddd','EeeeE','xxx'], 10**6),'Heloo':np.random.choice(['aa','bbbb','c','ddddd','EeeeE','xxx'], 10**6)})


print(df.shape)
(1000000, 2)


%timeit len(set(df.values.flatten()))

>>>89.5 ms ± 1.56 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)


%timeit np.unique(df.values).shape[0]

>>>1.61 s ± 25.6 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)


%timeit len(np.unique(df))

>>>1.85 s ± 229 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```